# how to install Chinese font in docker image in windowsservercore-1803

Tags: image, docker

Chinese language is not loading in docker image for my PDF report. Below is my docker code.

```
#Depending on the operating system of the host machines(s) that will build or run the containers, the image specified in the FROM statement may need to be changed.
#For more information, please see https://aka.ms/containercompat 

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-1803 AS final
EXPOSE 6009/tcp

WORKDIR /WebAPI.Output
COPY WebAPI.Output ./
COPY ./SSRSReportingReferences/t2embed.dll C:/Windows/SysWOW64

ENTRYPOINT ["cmd.exe", "/k", "WebAPI.exe"]
```

can anyone please guide me how to copy or install Chinese language in docker image.

Comment: can anyone please help me on this issue

Answer (score 2):

I just bumped into a similar issue where I needed Chinese fonts to properly export a PDF with Chinese characters.

My solution was to had the following commands before the ENTRYPOINT.

```
RUN apt-get install -y fontconfig fonts-wqy-zenhei
RUN fc-cache -fv
```

First command installs fontconfig (https://packages.debian.org/sid/fontconfig) and the Chinese Fonts (https://packages.debian.org/sid/fonts/).
Second command rebuilds the font cache.

Hope this help future people.